# Quick sorting in C. How to conquer the divides?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

So I am trying to teach myself how to implement a quick sort using C. I watched this video to learn the concept: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OLTJlwyIqQ

I think have mastered the concept of sorting to produce two separate sub-arrays, however I am confused about what would be the most efficient way to handle the many following sub-arrays. It seems you would need to keep track of the position of the sorted numbers within the array, and then process where those sorted numbers are in order to figure out where to begin sorting the next sub-array. This doesn't seem very efficient to me.

The way I am planning on handling this is to store the sorted numbers' position in a separate array, and do a scan of this array between ever iteration in order to determine which sub-array needs to be sorted next. Is this an acceptable method, or does this method lead to unnecessary extra processing time?

My code is as follows [including print functions used to help me debug, and hopefully help you understand my code :-) ]

Coded with Code::Blocks using GCC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int array[100];
    char sorted[100] = {0};
    int i;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 99;
    int pivot;
    int temp;

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand()%20;
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nLeft location:\t%#x\tLeft counter:\t%d", &array[left], left);
    printf("\nRight location:\t%#x\tRight counter:\t%d", &array[right], right);

    while(1)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            pivot = array[left];

            if(pivot > array[right])
            {
                temp = array[right];
                array[right] = pivot;
                array[left] = temp;
                pivot = array[right];
                break;
            }

            right--;
            if (left == right)
                break;
        }

        printf("\n\n\n\n");
        for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\nLeft location:\t%#x\tLeft counter:\t%d", &array[left], left);
        printf("\nRight location:\t%#x\tRight counter:\t%d", &array[right], right);

        if((right - left) < 1)
        {
            sorted[left] = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if((right - left) == 1)
        {
            sorted[right] = 1;
            break;
        }

        while(1)
        {
            pivot == array[right];

            if(pivot < array[left])
            {
                temp = array[left];
                array[left] = pivot;
                array[right] = temp;
                pivot = array[left];
                break;
            }

            left++;
            if (left == right)
                break;
        }

        printf("\n\n\n\n");
        for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\nLeft location:\t%#x\tLeft counter:\t%d", &array[left], left);
        printf("\nRight location:\t%#x\tRight counter:\t%d", &array[right], right);

        if((right - left) < 1)
        {
            sorted[left] = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if((right - left) == 1)
        {
            sorted[right] = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", sorted[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question ??

Comment: There are a number of different methods. A good discussion of the differing implementations can be found at [**Quicksort (wikipedia)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). As posted, your question is a bit over-broad for answer here.

Comment: The normal way to implement quick sort is to use recursion and store the pairs of indices to sub-arrays on the stack. An alternative would be to use iteration combined with an array used as a stack to hold the pairs of indices. During quick sort, only the pivot element of each sub-array is placed in it's final sorted position via partition. The remaining elements of each sub-array are only moved to their position relative to the pivot, either before or after the pivot. Eventually when the sub-array size reaches 2 (or 3 if pivot not included in split sub-array), do the elements get sorted.

Comment: @rcgldr "An alternative would be to use iteration combined with an array used as a stack to hold the pairs of indices." I think this helps keep things simple. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan - the worst case stack size is O(n), and assuming 2 indices stored per sub-array, the stack size would need to be n*2*sizeof(index).

Comment: the posted code needs a bit more work.  For instance this statement: `pivot == array[right];`  does nothing as it is a comparison `==`, I suspect you actually wanted to use an assignment: `pivot = array[right];`

Comment: in the calls to `printf()` for debugging, when printing the address of some variable, use `%p`  rather than `%#x`

Comment: the output of the calls to `printf()` in a loop, trying to print out the full array contents, clearly shows that the array is being set to all 0s except for one entry.  So there is a logic error in the code

Comment: before the first call to `rand()` there should be a single call to `srand()` to seed the random number generator.  suggest that call to `srand()` be: `#include <time.h> ....   srand( (unsigned) time( NULL ) );`

Comment: the posted code uses 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. I.E. 100 Suggest using a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name,  then using that meaningful name throughout the code.